# How to resolve this segmentation fault inside my do-while loop?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, segmentation-fault, knapsack-problem

> You have to transport a maximum of 15 different loads from one port to another. Carrying capacity of a cargo ship, which will transport those loads, is 50 tons. Loads are enumerated and the information about the weight of every load is given as input.
>
> Suppose that the weight of every load is smaller than or equal to 50 tons and greater than 0.
>
> You will read the weight of every load from the input in a single line. Your input will end with a -1. You will print the number of trips necessary.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 -1
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 15
> ```

But I get this error and whenever I give input to program

```
./vpl_execution: line 5: 15093 Bus error               (core dumped) ./main
```

By the way I seached about this situation, I think I am not out of array index or wrong using wrong pointers. Also, I saw same question in here with some solution but I want to know why code is not working and then solve the question on my own. Thank you so much for your help, all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   int w,i,t,sum,index;
    int list[16];
    w = 1;
    do
    {   
        scanf("%d",&w);
        list[index] = w;
        index++;
    }while(w >= 0);
    t = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < ((sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]))+1);i++)
    {
        sum =0;
        if(sum <= 50)
        {sum += list[i];}
        else
        {t++;}
    }

    printf("%d",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn to use your [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "from the input in a single line" your program does not respect that requirement, values can be placed in any number of lines

Comment: Are you sure you want to init `sum=0` each time again? You will always enter the `if` branch and only keep the last element in `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

> I get a segmentation error on my do while loop

The first segmentation fault happens at this line:

`list[index] = w;`

What do you think is the value of `index`?

You did not initialize it with a value, which probably should have been `0`.

Therefore, accessing `list[index]` is undefined behaviour. In your case, it caused a segmentation fault.

Then inside `for(i = 0;i < ((sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]))+1);i++)`

Accessing `list[i]` here can cause another segfault at the final value of `i`. You should remove the `+1` from `((sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]))+1)`.

**Solution:**

1. Do `index = 0;` once (initialization) before doing `list[index] = w;`
2. Remove the `+1` from `((sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]))+1)`

But it would be better to change

`for(i = 0;i < ((sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0])));i++)` to

`for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i)`

Because you already know the size of your `list` and `list[15]` is guaranteed to be `-1` if there are 15 weights. So, you just need to traverse upto `list[14]`.

This just removes the segfault, but there are still other problems in your code.

> I want to know why code is not working and then solve the question on
>   my own.

The logic inside your for-loop is wrong.

```
sum =0;
if(sum <= 50)
```

This condition is always true, and your else block which increments the value of `t` is never executed. Therefore, the output is always the initial value which you assign to `t`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211130/discussion-on-answer-by-ardent-coder-how-to-resolve-this-segmentation-fault-insi).

Answer (score 0):

first you have used an uninitialized variable `index` use `index=0`.

also as question said `a maximum of 15 different` , but you are using `((sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]))+1)` which aside from `+1` at the end of it ,which will cause passing boundaries of your array which will lead to undefined behavior, is wrong , because you will traverse array completely while it's possible that you have less elements in `array`. you should add a counter while you are scanning data and your second loop should be based on that.

also your code is different from question , if input is always `0 < input <= 50` you will never enter `else statement`(`t++`) and you will always print `0`. you are finding `sum` of weights and not count of them , and with the input explained in question you will always print `t=0`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I guess sizeof is not the smartest thing to do.